# Django throws an exception when it stops

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, exception

When I stop my django server by pressing `ctrl + break` as django says (or it restarts itself when the code changes), it throw this exception, but not every time:

```
Exception ignored in: <function Local.__del__ at 0x00000195D172EEA0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\asgiref\local.py", line 90, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\_weakrefset.py", line 59, in __iter__
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

That's normal with any python file when you stop it suddenly by a keyboard interruption, it's like a train is running and suddenly you press the brakes so it makes sense that some errors might happen, that's why sometimes it throws an exception and some times it doesn't,

Short answer: don't worry about it.

Comment: But it must be provided in Django. It's like a train is stopping at the station. It must be a normal action - stop the server. And I saw other people don't have this problem.